# Apache says httpd.exe -System error (.dll file missing)

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed XAMPP Version 7.0.6 with in Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. The control Panel version is 3.2.2. When I start Apache an error message pops-up showing "This program cannot start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". When I select OK the log screen, it shows the following details. I have tried reinstalling, but still the same problem. I even tried changing the port from 80 to 81,but in vain. Please help me..

PM 08:04:08  [main]     Initializing Control Panel

PM 08:04:08  [main]     Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate  32-bit

PM 08:04:08  [main]     XAMPP Version: 7.0.6

PM 08:04:08  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]

PM 08:04:08  [main]     Running with Administrator rights - good!

PM 08:04:08  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"

PM 08:04:08  [main]     Checking for prerequisites

PM 08:04:12  [main]     All prerequisites found

PM 08:04:12  [main]     Initializing Modules

PM 08:04:12  [main]     Starting Check-Timer

PM 08:04:12  [main]     Control Panel Ready

PM 08:04:24  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...

PM 08:04:24  [Apache]   Status change detected: running

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this

PM 08:06:55  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dll missing is sometimes the sign of Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 not being installed. Try installing it and running apache again.

Comment: Have you installed both the x32 and x64 version ?

Comment: I am using 32 bit system. So i cannot install x64 version.

Comment: You can try to download the dll manually and adding it in the apache folder.

Comment: If there is any other answer pls help me out

Comment: I have installed visual studio 10 ultimate (64-bit) successfully but still experienced the same problem too missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll. Need help to remedy the error please. where can i get that missing file please provide link.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should download dll file which is shown in your error massage according to your system bit (32bit or 64bit) from `dll-files.com`. This is zip file so extract this and copy this file in following path `c:\windows\system32` and paste them.

Open your xampp server again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the dl error is fixed by installing visual c++.
(I've seen some answer about installing visual c++ 2015).

My suggestion is you install visual c++ from 2008 to 2015 in order to see which of the other visual c++ versions you are missing.

After this your program should be up and running.